# ['“<BoundField value=14.99 errors=None>” value must be a decimal number.']

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am creating a restaurant model and I get an error

```
ValidationError at /api/restaurateur/create_meal/
['“<BoundField value=14.99 errors=None>” value must be a decimal number.']
```

How can I fix this error?

My view:

```
 @action(['POST'], detail=False, url_path='create_meal')
    def create_meal(self, *args, **kwargs):
        meal_data = self.request.data
        restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(owner=self.request.user)
        serializer = MealSerializer(meal_data)

        meal_create(title=serializer["title"],
                    description=serializer["description"],
                    price=serializer["price"],
                    restaurant=restaurant,
                    slug=serializer["slug"],
                    discount=serializer["discount"],
                    )
```

serivce.py

```
def meal_create(title, description, price, restaurant, slug, discount):
    meal = Meal.objects.create(title=title,
                               description=description,
                               price=price,
                               restaurant=restaurant,
                               slug=slug,
                               discount=discount,
                               )
    meal.save()
```

models.py

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    """Meal"""

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(default='The description will be later')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: can you share the code of MealSerializer ?

Comment: @ELhassane i solve this problem. I needed to write `description=serializer["description"]**.value**` in order for this to work correctly

Answer (score 0):

I was using modelserializer while retrieving data. I forgot to fetch data from serializer.validated_data and used direct serializer instead. In my views I updated the way I fetch validated data from serializer and it worked just fine. If you have the same issue it can be resolved this way.

This is how my code was while facing error

'key_name'=s_data['key_name']

I changed it to
'key_name'= s_data.validated_data['key_name']

hope it helps, Keep discovering.